# How to use etoken in asp.net webite in IIS enabled domain server

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, digital-signature

`
            //Signing a text using etoken class 3 platinum

```
      static byte[] Sign(string text, string certSubject)
    {
        // Access Personal (MY) certificate store of current user
        X509Store my = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.CurrentUser);
        my.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);

        // Find the certificate we'll use to sign            
        RSACryptoServiceProvider csp = null;
        foreach (X509Certificate2 cert in my.Certificates)
        {
            if (cert.Subject.Contains(certSubject))
            {
                // We found it. 
                // Get its associated CSP and private key
                csp = (RSACryptoServiceProvider)cert.PrivateKey;
            }
        }
        if (**csp == null**)
        {
            throw new Exception("No valid cert was found");
        }

        // Hash the data
        SHA1Managed sha1 = new SHA1Managed();
        UnicodeEncoding encoding = new UnicodeEncoding();
        byte[] data = encoding.GetBytes(text);
        byte[] hash = sha1.ComputeHash(data);

        // Sign the hash
        return csp.SignHash(hash, CryptoConfig.MapNameToOID("SHA1"));            
    }`
```

This codesnipt works well in visual studio but returns csp as null while using this code in domain server and also in local IIS Server.Please tell me what is the point that i am missing.

Answer (score 0):

The application pool identity has no access to the certificate.

Note that you are accessing the store of the current user. This works in VS because you are the current user. However, when you deploy the application to iis, the application pool identity is most probably different.

A recommendation - do not use the current user's cert store. The reason for that is when you switch app pool's identities, you have to log into each account and import certificates to corresponding cert stores. Rather, use local machine cert store which is shared by all users. There is a small issue here - you have to place certificates in the Personal store of the local machine store and manually set permission to access the private key to the app pool's identity.

You do this by right clicking the certificate, picking the "manage private keys" and then adding the app pool's identity to the list of users allowed to access the private key.

Comment: can you elaborate the process to place certificates in personal store and setting permission to access private key in detail.?

Answer (score 0):

When I change StoreLocation.CurrentUser to  StoreLocation.local machine,then it shows subject as localhost and issuer also as localhost.this changes generate appropriate  results.What more changes i need ,so to integrate the facility of using class 3 etoken in my website,so that any one can upload or login using their own class 3 etoken.